# Next.js Почему переменная окружения недоступна в хуке useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

В файле env.local находится переменная окружения INFURA_ID.
Внутри компонента, в хуке useEffect пытаюсь получить её process.env.INFURA_ID, но всё время получаю undefined.
Код:

```
'use client';

import styles from './page.module.css';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState('');
  const provider = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const infuraId = process.env.INFURA_ID;
    provider.current = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${infuraId}`);
  }, []);

  const balanceBtnClickHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const balance = await provider.current.getBalance(address);
      setBalance(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className='container'>
      <h1>Basic operations with blockchain</h1>
      <fieldset>
        <label htmlFor="eth-address">Please, input wallet address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="eth-address" onChange={(evt) => setAddress(evt.target.value)}></input>
        <button type='button' className={styles.btn} onClick={balanceBtnClickHandler}>
          Get balance
        </button>
      </fieldset>

      {balance && (
        <p>
          {`ETH Balance of ${address} - ${balance} ETH`}
        </p>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Почему нет доступа к переменной окружения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [справке](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser)

> Non-`NEXT_PUBLIC_` environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser.

> Не `NEXT_PUBLIC_` переменные среды, доступны только внутри `Node.js`, то есть недоступны в браузере.

`useEffect` - выполняется только в браузере, поэтому и переменная должна начинаться с `NEXT_PUBLIC_`

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решён.